# We have 4 non-discrete pens, 2 blue 2 red, and we remove them randomly one by one until we find a blue pen. What is our sample space?

Tags: probability

I think i know the answer if we deal with discrete pens:

$Ω=b,rb,rrb$

where, $b$=blue and $r$=red

but the non-discrete part confuses me a bit. How exactly does this change our sample space? Does it mean for example that if we draw the red pen first then its as if we drew both of them?

Comment: For discrete pens, you are writing $Ω=b,rb,rrb$. But $r1$ is different than $r2$ and so is $b1$ different than $b2$.

Comment: @MathLover So for discrete and non-discrete its essentially the same sample space, with the exception that you use distinct notation for pens of same color? Meaning non-discrete is Ω=b,rb,rrb and discrete Ω=b1,b2,r1b1,r1b2.. (and the rest of permutations)

Comment: What is the meaning of "discrete" when you refer to discrete/non-discrete pens?

Comment: The phrase "non-discrete" does not make sense since the four pens are separate objects.  Are you trying to say that pens of  the same color are indistinguishable?

Comment: Assuming by "discrete" you actually mean "distinguishable" (discrete means something much different), what MathLover is saying is that the sample space for distinguishable pens is $$\Omega =\{b_1, b_2, r_1b_1, r_1,b_2, r_2b_1, r_2b_2, r_1r_2b_1, r_1r_2b_2,  r_2r_1b_1, r_2r_1b_2\}$$ What you have listed is the sample space for the indistinguishable case.